# cakePHP- sql syntax based query to cake's array based query

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I need to execute this query from one of my controllers:

```
SELECT  `tel_no` 
        FROM  `donors` AS  `dnr` 
        LEFT JOIN  `donations` AS  `dn` ON  `dnr`.id =  `dn`.donor_id
        LEFT JOIN  `donation_methods` AS  `dm` ON  `dn`.donation_method_id =  `dm`.id
        WHERE  NOW() >= DATE_ADD(dn.created, INTERVAL dm.recovery_time DAY)
```

As you might notice, 3models are involved in this query. I am struggling with how to generate an array based query with cake for the above.

```
 $elligibleDonors = $this->Donor->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array('Donor.tel_no', 'Donor.email'),
        'conditions' => array('NOW() >= Donation.created + Donation_method.recovery_time'),
        'recursive' => 2
        ));
         $this->set('elligibleDonors', $elligibleDonors);
```

I tried this but a error states that column does not exis This is ofcourse a syntax error, one which I cannot figure out!

**[EDIT]**

relation ships are

Donor hasMany Donation
Donation belongsTo Donor
Donation belongsTo DonationMethod
DonationMethod hasMany Donation

```
$joins = array(
           array('table'=>'donations', 
                 'alias' => 'Donation',
                 'type'=>'left',
                 'conditions'=> array(
                 'Donation.donor_id = Donor.id'
           )),
           array('table'=>'donation_methods', 
                 'alias' => 'DonationMethod',
                 'type'=>'left',
                 'conditions'=> array(
                 'DonationMethod.id = Donation.donation_method_id'
           ))
         );
```

I ve found that this is what I want, but where do I put the 'WHERE' clause condition within this code?

Comment: Why not using the query itself, with table aliasing so cake will sort it as standard array?

Comment: Do you mean, using the query() method? if so, what about sql injection. PS. I would need to add to the conditions based on user filtering.

Comment: Yes, `query()`. generally, cake will sanitize any input. it will be done with cake's objects - that you can call yourself (check the api).
As to the error - which column?!?! please supply some more info. like table structure and the exact errors

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `join` option in Cake, if default `find` doesn't suit your needs.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables

Comment: I have just editted my question! could you have a look? thanks

Comment: For the conditions, just put a `conditions` option in your `$options` array. Look at the second example in the link.